# Pulling the data from remote sql server to local sql server at fixed interval

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
public class jdbc {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("not loaded");
        }

            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://172.**.**.**:1433;" +"databaseName=dbname;user=user;password=pwd;";
            Connection con=null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("CONNECTED");

            try {
             stmt = con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * FROM [dbname].[dbo].[VwZoneCount]");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.print(rs.getString("Zone Name")+"\t");
                    System.out.print(rs.getInt("Zone Count")+"\t");
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("Phase Name"));


;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
}
```

From this code i am pulling the data from remote sql server .I need to insert this data into my local machine sql server .How do i do that ??

Also i need to run the insert program every 15 min automatically indefinitely .

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/08/10/694657.aspx

Comment: Check the linked server concept: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3085211/Linked-Servers-on-MS-SQL-Part-1.htm